# Removing global menu bar Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, menu, menu-bar

I like that when I hover the cursor over the menu bar and the options appear.

However, find it's annoying that all the menu bars are at the top of the desktop.

**I tried removing them with:**

```
sudo apt-get remove indicator-appmenu
sudo apt-get autoremove appmenu-gtk appmenu-gtk3 appmenu-qt
```

But neither worked. Does someone know how to remove the *global menu bar* without breaking the hover-over feature?

Comment: have you tried **System -> Appearance ->  Behavior -> show menus for a window (in the window's title bar)**

Answer (score 2):

By uninstalling `indicator-appmenu appmenu-gtk, appmenu-gtk3 and appmenu-qt`you brought your system back to where **a menu bar is a menu bar** and **a title bar is a title bar** and **global menus don't exist**.  This also means that any functionality went with the components removed.  Thus Mohamed's advice. To keep the **hover over** effect leave (or reinstall) `indicator-appmenu appmenu-gtk, appmenu-gtk3 and appmenu-qt`and in the **System Settings** go to **Appearance -> Behavior ->** and click **show menus for a window (in the window's title bar)**.